# How to compile a single project in a solution that has other projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I've had the errors shown in the picture and I suspect the first 2 are because it is trying to execute all projects but the last 2 I'm not sure (think it might be just cascade from the other 2)

I have 3 projects in my solution but I just want to compiple ParserTest... is there a way to compile only this project without changing the others to Class Library? (and even to change them to class library, is there an option to change it or do I have to create a new project and copy all files?)

[image]

Any hints/suggestions are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your "JJTree Stuff" project has an entrypoint defined that you haven't provided. Since it isn't a Class Library - you need to provide it. Either provide a `static` method matching the required one in your project properties (in yours its the default - `Main`), or change them to class libraries. Its a compiler issue - so you need to provide what it asks for.

Comment: Is there a way to change it to a library or do I need to create a new project and copy all files?

Comment: "and even to change them to class library, is there an option to change it or do I have to create a new project and copy all files?)" Right-click on the project name in Solution Explorer, select Properties (last entry on menu), on the Application tab change the "Output type" drop-down option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the "Output type" of your project.

Right click the project in the Solution Explorer and go to Properties.

Under the "Application" tab, there is an Output type option:

[image: Output type]